# react-native-redux: changes to state not rerendering child component

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

its possible I dont fully understand the situations under which react-native componenets rerender when state is changed.

I have a custom FlatList component called MyFlatList.....which is the child of a larger screen component.

I pass redux value into MyFlatList as per below

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  rdx_places: state.places,
});
```

....then I use it in the `renderItem` prop of the FlatList as below

```
renderItem={({item}) => { 
let placeName = this.props.rdx_places[item.place_id].placeName;
```

...then I use variable pulled from redux in return statement

```
return (variable placeName used here)
```

When I trigger action creator to change redux state (`state.places`)..I can see it successfully updates state in Redux....however FlatList does not rerender.

Interestingly the parent component DOES rerender (parent also has same state passed into it via `mapStateToProps`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Documentation of FlatList

> extraData
>
> A marker property for telling the list to re-render (since it implementsPureComponent). If any of your renderItem, Header, Footer, etc. functions depend on anything outside of the data prop, stick it here and treat it immutably.

Any data dependency your FlatList relies on that changes and should cause the FlatListe to rerender has to be supplied by extraData.

So you provide data by supplying it to data  and then pass the state that might change to extraData. Then, the component rerenders whenever extraData changes.